# FirstOrDefault inline null checking

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have following code :

```
var result = new Collection<object>();

result.Add(
     list.Select(s => new
     {
          s.Name,
          Rating = s.Performance.OrderByDescending(o => o.Year).FirstOrDefault().Rating
     })
);
```

If there's no record found in `Performance`, it will give me `NullException` which is expected because I'm trying to get `Rating` property from `null` value so my question is how to set `null` if `FirstOrDefault()` is `null` and get `Rating` value if not.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do this:

```
Rating = s.Performance.OrderByDescending(o => o.Year)
                      .Select(o => o.Rating)
                      .FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Enumerable.DefaultIfEmpty Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360179(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
Rating = s.Performance.OrderByDescending(o => o.Year)
                      .Select(o => o.Rating)
                      .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
                      .First()
```